# Getting v-for's loop index inside Blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a VueJS component which gets a variable via a Laravel controller and passed correctly through the props[] array. One of the view files has a v-for loop inside of it which iterates the data from the controller and the flow works just fine except one thing - There is a one-to-many relationship between the `Operator` (model #1) and the `Comment` (model #2), so basically - what I'm trying to do is to show in the operators' table how many comments each operator has.
I know the relationship works just fine, and I tried `var_dump`ing the `$comments` and the `$data` around the view and it seems like the data is correct.

Here is part of the listing view which iterates the operators and creates a table with their data -

```
...
...
<operator-listing
        :data="{{ $data->toJson() }}"
        :url="'{{ url('admin/operators') }}'"
        :comments="{{ $comments }}"
        inline-template>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="(item, index) in collection" :key="item.id" :class="bulkItems[item.id] ? 'bg-bulk' : ''">
<td class="bulk-checkbox">
<input class="form-check-input" :id="'enabled' + item.id" type="checkbox" v-model="bulkItems[item.id]" v-validate="''" :data-vv-name="'enabled' + item.id"  :name="'enabled' + item.id + '_fake_element'" @click="onBulkItemClicked(item.id)" :disabled="bulkCheckingAllLoader">
<label class="form-check-label" :for="'enabled' + item.id">
</label>
</td>

<td>@{{ item.id }} </td>
<td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
<td>
<label class="switch switch-3d switch-success">
<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" v-model="collection[index].enabled" @change="toggleSwitch(item.resource_url, 'enabled', collection[index])">
<span class="switch-slider"></span>
</label>
</td>

<td>@{{ item.rank }}</td>
<td>@{{ item.total_score }}</td>
<td>
<!-- 
     Here i am trying to do something like this -
     {{ count($comments->where('operator_id',$item_id)) }}
-->
</td>
```

Please notice the comment inside the last `<td>` which say -

```
<!-- 
     Here i am trying to do something like this -
     {{ count($comments->where('operator_id',$item_id)) }}
-->
```

The `$item_id` there is just for a mockup, it's not really defined anywhere.
Since I use the blade templating `{{ }}` and not Vue's in this `<td>`, it means I dont have an access to `{{ item.id }}` from Vue's loop iteration, the one I actually need to retrieve for this ->where statement.

**Is there a way to pass `@{{ item.id }}` from Vue's v-for loop into a blade template?**

- Both models (`'Operator'` and `'Comment'`) have `->belongsTo` and `->hasMany` (relatively) methods which work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in javascript only

```
<td>
    @{{ comments.filter(comment => comment.operator_id === item.id).length }}
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks.
The only reason is that i am a PHP developer, and this is my comfort zone, so sometimes it's not easy to make these 'jumps' between the languages' functionalities.

Comment: @GonrasKarols I understand, it happens to even devs who are comfortable in the lang - sometimes it just happens - no worries